# Uploading image to WCF json service

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have function in `wcf` json service take two parameters to upload an image:

```
Public Function UploadDamageImage(ByVal UploadDamageImageRequest As UploadDamageImageRequest) As UploadDamageImageResponse
```

How can I send an image as a parameter to this function as bytes?

I'm using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

Comment: the parameters:                                                                                            Public FileContent As Byte()                                                                     Public FileName As String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a UIImage as bytes to a function, you can first convert the UIImage to a NSData object and then get the byte array from that.

```
UIImage *image = // your image...
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); 
NSString *byteArr = [data base64Encoding];
```

For the second line of code, the [Apple Docs for UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html) explains:

> ...you can get an NSData object containing either a PNG or JPEG representation of the image data using the UIImagePNGRepresentation and UIImageJPEGRepresentation functions.

Comment: Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7fe31b01a900 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe318d0c130>